# django : raspberry pi LED using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, raspberry-pi

I'm developing my own WEB using Django web frame.
I'm trying to turn Raspberry pi LED on only using Javascript.

```
 var gpio = require("pi-gpio");
    gpio.open(16, "output", function(err){
      gpio.write(16, 1, function(){
        gpio.close(16);
    });
  });
```

```
<script src='../static/bundle.js'></script>
```

I downloaded browserify to use require module in my browser
SO, I made  by typing 'npm run build' in terminal.
But, I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
  at Object.5.child_process(bundle.js:436)
  at s (bundle.js:1)
  at bundle.js:1
  at Object.1.pi-gpio (bundle.js:2)
  at s (bundle.js:1)
  at e (bundle.js:1)
  at bundle.js:1
```